# Testing private method in Ruby (rspec)

Tags: ruby, rspec

Yes, I know, that testing private methods it's not a good idea (and I
read this thread - http://www.ruby-forum.com/topic/197346 - and some
others)

But how can I test the following code?

I use xmpp4r. In my public method `#listen` I start receive jabber
messages like so:

```rb
def listen
  @client.add_message_callback do |m|
    do_things_with_message(m)
  end
end

private
def do_things_with_message(m)
  #
end
```

`#add_message_callback` - runs block, when message come (in different thread)

So, testing `#listen` method it's difficult and it more testing xmpp4r
than my `#do_things_with_message`

How to do all right and test `#do_things_with_message`?:)
(http://www.ruby-forum.com/topic/197346#859664)

*Refactor private methods to a new object* essentialy would be as I making them a public (and class with one method - it's senselessly

**EDIT:**
This is more a theoretical question about clean code and the correct tests.
In my first link people argue that the test private methods poorly.
I don't want cheat with `#send`, but also I don't see any viable ways to refactor

Comment: This is not a real question. The thread you link to already gives you several techniques to accomplish what you want and some good advise about how to shape your design around the problem. You can cheat and use `send` or turn the method public in your tests, or you can refactor.

Comment: @dbenhur I don't want cheat, but also I don't see any viable ways to refactor

Comment: If your code is complex enough that you need to test the private method (i.e. it's not just a simple Model.find or whatever), then it may very well be complex enough to be worth extracting into a separate class, anyway.

Answer (score 136):

You can call a private method in ruby using [the `send` method](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.2/Object.html#method-i-send). Something like this:

```
@my_object = MyObject.new
@my_object.send(:do_things_with_message, some_message)
```

In a test that would look something like:

```
it "should do a thing" do
  my_object = MyObject.new
  my_object.send(:do_things_with_message, some_message)
  my_object.thing.should == true
end
```

Comment: I know about `#send`. It more theoretical question about clean code and right tests...

Comment: @Andrey Could you please provide any reference

Answer (score 16):

Putting aside the question of whether or not you ***should*** be testing a private method, it is very possible in Ruby to temporarily make a private method public. Here is what I mean:

```
# Metaprogrammatical magic to temporarily expose
# a Class' privates (methods).
class Class
  def publicize_methods
    saved_private_instance_methods = self.private_instance_methods
    self.class_eval { public *saved_private_instance_methods }
    yield
    self.class_eval { private *saved_private_instance_methods }
  end
end
```

You would use `publicize_methods` like this:

```
ClassToTest.publicize_methods do
  ...
  do_private_things_with_message(m).should ???
  ...
end
```

Answer (score 3):

You probably heard this thought in all the resources that you mention, but the proper "theoretical" way to do it would be to test that `@client` receives `add_message_callback`, and then indirectly test your private methods with integration tests. The whole point of unit testing is that you can change implementation, and your tests will still pass

Comment: "it would be to test that @client receives add_message_callback" - maybe you right... but it still be testing xmpp4r gem, jabber server and my network, etc. real work and real output do `#do_things_with_message`. `#add_message_callback` just launch new thread

Comment: Adding a listener is not gem code, otherwise you wouldn't have to write it. If you want to test your private method, either make it public or use `send(:do_things_with_message, args)`